# Why is Jekyll not working in local when I add a new post?

Tags: github, jekyll

I am testing my `github` site with Jekyll, but when I add a new post it is not generating the post in the `_posts` folder, so it can't get `site.posts` in `index.html`.
I had `jekyll serve` running in local.

My folder:

[image: error folder]

The local page:

[image: get 0 post]

The local:

[image: local jekyll]

However,  it works fine on the `github` site. So what's the problem?

Comment: To clarify the question. Generally, we write blog in **_post/** directory manually, and generate the post into **_site/post/** directory by `jekyll s`.  What do you mean by it generated the post into _post?

Comment: I mean i running `jekyll serve` or `sekyll build ` don't work to generate post  into `_post` .

Comment: Do you have the yaml front matter in your posts? Jekyll ignores files without front matter. http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This a Jekyll 3.x behavior.
Posts with a date in the future are not published, except if you :

- set a `future: true` variable in `_config.yml`

or

- do a `jekyll serve --future`

This is not a problem under Jekyll 2.x and Github pages.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: I could see my code on github pages, but not locally. The problem seemed to be with incompatibility between jekyll-paginate and the current Rubygems version of Jekyll: 3.4.0.

I uninstalled that version of jekyll with `gem uninstall jekyll` and then installed the version used by [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/versions/): 3.3.1.

Works like a charm now!